# I have a user in our primary store with the "Service" as their last name

Tags: active-directory, wso2-identity-server

We have two users in our primary userstore that their legal Last name is **"Service"**, but they are not showing in WSO2 IS 5.10 due to their last name. When searching in the user list I get a "No matching users found" error.

If I update the last name in Active Directory to something like "Servic" or "Service." they do appear as a user in WSO2 IS.

Where or how can I configure WSO2 to allow users with "Service" in their last name to authenticate? The Primary Userstore is ActiveDirectory based, so they can login to Microsoft 365 services as well as any other service not using WSO2 IS.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- Open your `user-mgt.xml` file located in the `<IS_HOME>/repository/conf` directory.
- Under `<UserStoreManager>` check the property value configured for `UserNameListFilter` property
- It should have excluded the users who have last name as Service in user listing filer
  similar to `(&amp;(objectClass=person)(!(sn=Service)))`

To update it you can configure the userstore property through deployment.toml file

```
[user_store] 
user_name_list_filter = "(objectClass=person)"
```

Comment: Unfortunately that is not the case in our configuration, this is what we have under user-mgt.xml

    <Property name="UserNameListFilter">(objectClass=person)</Property>

Comment: In your user store properties, is there any config that excludes the  last name property being equals to Service

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is expected behavior.  In the WSO2 code base, it specifically excludes any account with the name of "Service" as seen in this file in the comment:

https://github.com/wso2/carbon-kernel/blob/v4.6.0/core/org.wso2.carbon.user.core/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/user/core/ldap/ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager.java#L966

This is perhaps a security concern.  But why only Service, why not also svc or other names that users might choose?